# Android - java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: select * from table where rowid=40495

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my activity, I requested to API and get data from that and insert data in my SQLite database. Then I call this method:

```
public long getResultCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long cnt  = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME);
    return cnt;
}
```

This method is in other java class and it works correctly in my activity. After calling this method I call the method:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getId(int i, int j) {

    ArrayList<Integer> array_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "
            + TABLE_NAME
            + " limit " + i + "," + j
            , null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
        array_list.add(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID))));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

and when I write this code after that:

```
temp = db.getId(min * 5, min * 5 + 5);

for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {

        Cursor rs = db.getResult(temp.get(i));
        rs.moveToFirst();
        ...
        rs.close();
    }
```

an error occurs:

> 11-08 19:16:35.108 15365-15365/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 15365
>                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: select * from table where rowId=40495
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:146)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:135)
>                                                          at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
>                                                          at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:243)
>                                                          at com.myapp.app.MyFragment.populateListView(MyFragment.java:327)
>                                                          at com.myapp.app.MyFragment$GetArticles.onPostExecute(MyFragment.java:693)
>                                                          at com.myapp.app.MyFragment$GetArticles.onPostExecute(MyFragment.java:497)
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)

**getResult** method is this:

```
public Cursor getResult(int Id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_ID + "=" + Id + "", null);
    res.close();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: If the exception is in the last segment you posted, then `getID()` is returning closed cursors. You didn't post its code.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Please post `getID()` code. The `getid()` you posted is something different.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getResult()` method is returning closed `Cursor`s. You cannot use closed cursors for anything really.

Either don't `close()` the cursor in `getResult()`. Or capture the data you need prior to closing it and return the data, not the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `res.close` before `return array_list;`

Comment: You mean I add **res.close()** before return array_list in method **getId**? I try it but that error occurred again.

Comment: This is not a solution to the stacktrace OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {

        Cursor rs = db.getResult(temp.get(i));
        rs.moveToFirst();
        ...
        rs.close();
    }
```

Are there any conditions on closing cursor? If not — cursor will be closed after the first iteration and you will get exception on the 2nd one.